# Проблема с tcp-сервером c#

Tags: c#, tcp-ip

При создании экземпляра класса `InputUserInfoForm` сервер принимает соединение, хотя в данном классе нет ничего для соединения с ним. Уже час ищу ошибку, не могу понять в чём проблема.
Вот код класса `InputUserInfoForm`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TextEditorClient
{
    public partial class InputUserInfoForm : Form
    {
        private string fileName = "";
        private int fileNameLength = 0;
        public InputUserInfoForm(int fnl)
        {
            fileNameLength = fnl;
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Писатель");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Обозреватель");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            fileName = textBox1.Text;
            this.Close();
        }
        public int CheckFileName()
        {
            fileName = textBox1.Text;
            if (fileName == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Имя файла не может быть пустым.", "Ошибка!");
                return 1;
            }
            if (fileName.Length >= fileNameLength)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Максимальная длина имени файла 50 символов.", "Ошибка!");
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Код сервера:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace TextEditorServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static int port = 8888;
        static TcpListener server;
        private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
                server.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection... ");
                    TcpClient clientConnection = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                    ClientClass newClient = new ClientClass(clientConnection);
                    Thread newClientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(newClient.Process));
                    newClientThread.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (server != null)
                    server.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Дело было в том, что при подключении клиента к серверу, сервер сразу начинает работу, хотя данные от клиента ещё не поступили.